# Add day to each line of csv file in unix bash

Tags: bash, unix, csv, text

I'm trying to teach myself unix bash to manipulate large text files (.CSV in this case). I'd like to add the day of the week to every line of a file, based n the date in that line. I have some idea of how to accomplish the individual parts, but can't quite put the parts together. Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers.

To find each date (I need to put commas in between columns too):

```
sed -i.bak "s/(0-9)(0-9)\/(0-9)(0-9)\/(0-9)(0-9)(0-9)(0-9)/\1\2,\3\4,\5\6/" datafile.txt
```

To find day of week (using 20150311 as an example. I'd like to use the date within the line):

```
date -d 20150311 +%A
```

How can I somehow put these together for each line? I know I need to create a variable out of the regular expression, use that with the date command above, and then somehow append it to the end of each line using:

```
sed -i.bak "s/$/,DAYVARIABLE/" datafile.txt
```

Assuming the data file is formatted something like:

RandomString,AnotherRandomString,01/01/1982,MoreRandomString

Thanks again

Comment: How are you getting `20150311`? Is it static value for each row?

Comment: 20150311 is merely an example. I'm looking to add the day of the week that corresponds to the date within that line. I'll make this clear, thanks.

Comment: What date is 00/00/1982?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) as

```
sed "s/$/, $(date -d 20150311 +%A)/"
```

**Test**

```
$ cat input
qwerty
asdf 
abb asdf
bbb
zxc
abc
qweabcqwe

$ sed "s/$/, $(date -d 20150311 +%A)/" input
qwerty, Wednesday
asdf , Wednesday
abb asdf, Wednesday
bbb, Wednesday
zxc, Wednesday
abc, Wednesday
qweabcqwe, Wednesday
```

Comment: But this only adds a static string to each line, not the date from within that line.

Comment: what tripleee said. would there be a way to use the same approach and use the groups from the date regex (`/1 /2` etc.) in the subshell there?

Answer (score 2):

There is an extension to GNU `sed` which allows you to embed an external command in the replacement part, but for portability and clarity, I would switch to a different tool.

```
perl -MPOSIX -i.bak -pe 's|(,(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4}),.*)|
   "$1," . strftime("%A", 0, 0, 0, $2, $3-1, $4) |e' file.csv
```

This is assuming your dates are dd/mm/yyyy; swap around `$2` and `$3` if your input is (wacky) American mm/dd/yyyy.

This is using the Perl POSIX `strftime` module, which accepts a rather complex list of arguments to specify the date (it's a 7-element list as returned by the Perl standard `localtime` function).  There are various wrappers which would allow for more convenient date handling, but they are not included in the standard Perl library, so they would add an external dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script:

**Sample Input:**

```
cat file
RandomString,AnotherRandomString,01/01/1982,MoreRandomString
FooBar,AnotherRandomString,01/10/1990,SomeRandomString
```

**Code:**

```
while IFS=, read -ra arr; do
    len=$((${#arr[@]} - 2))
    printf "%s," "${arr[@]}"
    date -d "${arr[$len]}" '+%A'
done < file
```

**Output:**

```
RandomString,AnotherRandomString,01/01/1982,MoreRandomString,Friday
FooBar,AnotherRandomString,01/10/1990,SomeRandomString,Wednesday
```

**Explanation:**

```
IFS=, read -ra arr            # populate an array arr with comma as separator
len=$((${#arr[@]} - 2))       # get length(array) -1 in len to extract date
printf "%s," "${arr[@]}"      # print array arr with comma as field separator
date -d "${arr[$len]}" '+%A'  # print day of the week for date value
```

Comment: this is fantastic. would you be able to briefly provide more explanation about what those middle 3 lines are doing? Thanks

Comment: Did it not work for you since you've remove accepted mark from my answer? (Have added explanation in answer)

Comment: it actually gets the date for the wrong day, ive just worked out. because of the structure of the date argument, which is YYYYMMDD.

Comment: From where is `YYMMDD` coming from? Your examples says: `01/01/1982`

Comment: @Jordan: Are you sure you've provided correct sample data in your question?